# Modal dentro de um repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, modal

Tenho um link dentro de um repeater que chama um modal para exibir mais detalhes da lista que esta sendo exibida por esse repeater. O problema é que não estou conseguindo mostrar o modal para cada linha do repeater. Estou colocando o modal dentro do repeater e chamando através do ItemDataBound, porém ele não mostra os resultado corretos.

O objeto é clicar no link exibido por cada linha e mostrar o modal correspondente a cada linha.

Link que chama o modal:

```
<a title="Clique para mais detalhes do total de gravações" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#RedolDetailsStatusModal">&nbsp<i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></a>
```

ItemDataBound do Repater:

```
protected void repeaterTranscriptionProcessType_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{    
    DataSet lobjDS = meuDataSet();
    //GridView que está dentro do modal
    Control l_GridViewControl = e.Item.FindControl("grdGrid");
    ((GridView)l_GridViewControl).DataSource = lobjDS;
    ((GridView)l_GridViewControl).DataBind();
}
```

Comment: você precisa passar alguma informação da linha para o modal, algo como `<a valor=<%#Eval("AlgumValor")%>...>`

Comment: Consegui passar usando um data-id para passar a informação, obrigado!